# Highcharts display label for pie chart using html table as data source

Tags: highcharts

I have a working pie chart that uses data from a HTML table. I trying to get the corresponding label to show on the chart. Current it shows "slice" on all slices. Here is a jsFiddle link www.jsfiddle.net/codedecks/YJsSg/. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Did some more searching and found a couple of sample that was was able to use. In case any one else is looking for the same thing here is the link to the jsFiddle www.jsfiddle.net/codedecks/KB6Zy/.